# Six Unique numbers which generate unique sum during addition

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, permutations

I have six numbers which are like points that satisfy certain condition.

If the condition is satisfied that point will be given or else $0$ will be assigned as points.

I am Storing the points in six columns as below in the table:

```
PointA   PointB    PointC     PointD     PointE      PointF           Sum  
   X       Y         Z          M          N           L         (X+Y+Z+M+N+L)  
   X       0         Z          M          N           0         (X+Y+0+Z+M+0)  
   0       Y         Z          0          N           0         (0+Y+Z+0+N+0)  
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

In the above case $X, Y, Z, M, N, L$ are unique numbers.

Their sum should be unique column wise

The Point $A$ column can either have $X$ points or Zero, Similarly, Point $D$ column can have $M$ points or Zero at its column. Like that every column will have its respective point or zero.

The sum of $X+Y+Z+M+N+L$ should be unique

In total there are $720$ combinations.

How to find  numbers at $X, Y, Z, M, N, L$

Comment: If your six numbers are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32, all the sums will be distinct. But where do you get 720 combinations? I see only 64.

Comment: What do you mean by "The Sum of X+Y+Z+M+N+L should be unique"?

Comment: No two sum in that sum column should have same value

Comment: Are you talking to me? You have to put @Gerry if you want to be sure I see something directed to me.

Answer (score 1):

Comment elevated to answer, at request of OP:

If your six numbers are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32, all the sums will be distinct. There will be 64 (not 720) of them.