# Linearly growing sets of numbers which allow for a unique decomposition

Tags: number-theory

I'm searching for sets $B=\{b_1,...b_n\}$ of $n$ distinct positive natural numbers with the following condition:

1. The sum $\sum_{k=1}^n b_k=b^\star$ (where each element appears once), is unique, i.e. no other sum of $n$ elements from $B$ gives $b^\star$.
2. The largest element in $B$ grows only polynomial with $n$.

Clearly of [powers of $2$ would suffice the first condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/232112/19341) and there is also the [Fibonacci Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem), but both examples don't match my second condition.

The [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) seems to ask for something simliar in a certain way, but it also doesn't match quite.

Any help appreciated...

**Update**

So far, brute force numerical experiments revealed the following sets with minimal maximal element:

- $n=4: B=\{1,2,5,7\}$
- $n=5: B=\{1,2,6,12,14\}$
- $n=6: B=\{1,3,11,22,23,27\}$

Comment: I don’t understand which sums in Condition 1 are required to be distinct. Since the set $A$ consists of $n$ elements, there is only one sum $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$, where each element of $A$ appears once, namely, the sum of all elements of $A$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky another valid sum would have the first element $n$ times. A little like partitions...

Comment: I still don’t understand which sums are valid and which are not. :(

Comment: @AlexRavsky just pick any $n$ elements from $A$

Comment: But then in your example of $A$ for $n=4$ if we pick $a_1=a_2=a_5=5$ and $a_4=1$, we obtain a sum $16$. If we pick $a_1=a_2=7$ and $a_3=a_4=1$, we obtain the same sum $16$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky that's OK since the only unique sum should be 15=1+2+5+7 in this case, others don't matter

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that these sets have been studied, under the name "$B_n$ sets" (usually people have used $h$ in place of $n$) or "$B_h[1]$ sets".

[Bose and Chowla (see Theorem 1)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02566968.pdf) gave an explicit algebraic construction of a $B_h$ set with $m$ elements, all of which are integers between $0$ and $m^h$. Up to the constant in front of $m^h$, this order of growth is best possible (by the pigeonhole principle).

See [O'Bryant's survey](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS11) for more constructions and references on this topic.

Comment: +1, let me repeat [Theorem 1](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/COURSES/858/S13/BoseChowla.pdf): If $m=p^n$ (where $p$ is prime) we can find $m$ non-zero integers (less than $m^r$)
$$
(1.0) \hskip1.0in d_1=1, d_2,...d_m
$$
such that the sums
$$
(1.1) \hskip1.0in d_{i_1}+d_{i_2}+\cdots+d_{i_r}
$$
$1\le i_1\le i_2 ... \le i_r \le m$ are all different $\bmod (m^r-1)$.
$$
$$
But isn't $r=m$ in my case?

Comment: Interestingly the set given as example 1 with $m=5, r=3$: $\{1,14,34,103,119 \}$ works, even for all sums of five elements. I checked all combinations numerically (with and without $\bmod 124$), which sounds promising...

Comment: Thanks for the best help so far

Comment: Hi Greg, I just realized that the constructed sets of $d_k$ would additionally make all sums of $r$ terms, including ones with repetitions, unique. That's way more than I ask for, or does that make the construction easier in terms of symmetry?